# MapReduce find word length frequency

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in MapReduce and I wanted to ask if someone can give me an idea to perform word length frequency using MapReduce. I've already have the code for word count but I wanted to use word length, this is what I've got so far.

```
public class WordCount  {

public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
    }
}
```

}

Thanks ...

Comment: Can you explain with an example.

Comment: welcome to SE, share examples & your efforts to be served better. The code you posted seems to be a straight `Ctrl+c` & `Ctrl+v` !   Please try to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For word length frequency, `tokenizer.nextToken()` shouldn't be emit as `key`. The length of that string actually be considered. So your code will do fine with just the following change and is sufficient :

```
word.set( String.valueOf( tokenizer.nextToken().length() ));
```

Now if you give deep look, you will realize that `Mapper` output key should no longer be `Text` although it works. Better use an `IntWritable` key instead :

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private IntWritable wordLength = new IntWritable();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            wordLength.set(tokenizer.nextToken().length());
            context.write(wordLength, one);
        }
    }
}
```

Although most of the `MapReduce` examples use `StringTokenizer`, it's cleaner and advisable to use `String.split` method. So make the changes accordingly.